# Time Passage Naked Eye Viewing Distant stars

Tags: speed-of-light

My question surrounds the time it takes to see a star and it's ending. OK, a star is 100 light years away, so it takes 100 years to see the light from it when that star 1st begins sending light. 100 years. For simplicity purposes, lets say I saw that star for 100 of my years, so it has lasted at least for 100 years. Then the star dies and stops transmitting light, but I'll still see that light for another 100 years, is this all correct?

Comment: It takes a *very* long time for a star to stop glowing after it's stopped doing nuclear fusion. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dwarf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. When we look at a star, we see any brightening or fading of the star at the same pace as it happens on the star itself, but with a delay that depends on the star's distance from us.